# Switch/Checkout with TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

I'm doing switch/check out fairly regularly...

The quickest way I can determine the current branch is to right click the folder and look at the "Commit" command (or click Properties, Git tab or from the command line use git status).

Are there better ways to know the current branch?

I'm considering cloning the "other" branch to a folder name that includes the branch name so it reaches the top level of the GUI and is obvious.  Is this a common practice?

Comment: Git status or use a different tool that shows your current branch. There are lots of gui client: https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis Some free some not. I use gitkraken (pay) but something like ungit should show you your current branch all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that people tend to have quite different workflows when it comes to Git so there isn't necessarily a better or best way, just what works for that person.  Personally I have ended up over the years with an approach where I do checkout, stash, push, pull on the command line and use Tortoise Git for doing commits, reviewing history and managing remotes.

In answer to your specific questions:

> Are there better ways to know the current branch?

As mentioned above, I use the command line quite a lot so a quick glance shows me the branch name immediately. This feature is provided by [Cmder](https://cmder.net/). In the screenshot below the branch and remote are shown in white indicating that there are no changes in the repo. It changes to red to indicate uncommitted changes to tracked files and yellow to indicate untracked changes e.g. a new file:
[image]

There are also other apps like Git Extensions which show the current branch in the UI.

> I'm considering cloning the "other" branch to a folder name that
> includes the branch name so it reaches the top level of the GUI and is
> obvious. Is this a common practice?

I've never come across this so I don't think it is common. You would need to be careful that you don't accidentally make changes in the wrong repo clone. I have done this and it can be very time-consuming to resolve! It might also be a significant waste of drive space depending on the size of the repo.